# CSS div with background-video with "background-size: cover"-like properties

Tags: html, css

So I want to have something like this where the blue image is substituted with a video. Is this even possible?

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/2996x1400/003399/ccc.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/cc0000/ccc.jpg">
<p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried quite a few things so far but nothing really worked. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a video as a background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477890/using-a-video-as-a-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```css
.logo {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative; /* requires for to position video properly */
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover; /* combined with 'absolute', works like background-size, but for DOM elements */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <video playsinline webkit-playsinline autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/cc0000/ccc.jpg">
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! (I only had to change the css a bit further to "height: 100vh; width: 100vw;" and was successful putting it into my website!)

Answer (score 1):

```
The following is a snippet of css coding.  
.overlay { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100; 
  left: 40;  
  width: 150;  
  height: 150;  
  -o-object-fit: cover;  
  object-fit: cover;  
}  



video {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center;
     object-position: center;
}
```

I successfully used the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="main">
                    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                        <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="videos/output.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                        <source src="videos/video2.webm" type="video/webm">
                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <p><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br> </p>
                    <img style="float:left" src="images/result06.png" alt="Tensioning Grid Loop 4" width="100" height="100"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found help at https://codeconvey.com/html5-video-overlay-text/
I had to put in the line breaks to move the small image down.